Any way to spoof cursor location in bash (in response to \033[6n)?
I am working on a project that requires me to send a particular location of the cursor on the terminal. Since the coordinates are quite large, it is not possible to actually move the cursor to that position. The way it works is I send an ssh request to a server and the server then queries my terminal using the \033[6n ANSI code. How can I spoof the response from my terminal to send a particular set of coordinates back instead of my actual cursor position?

You can use an Expect script that waits for that escape sequence, then sends whatever you want.

Cursor and screen are the domain of the terminal and its driver, and to the extent that there is any interpretation of ANSI escape sequences, it is the terminal driver that is responsible for that. You can intercept escape sequences and substitute your own handling, but this is pretty nasty. (Nasty design, not necessarily nasty to implement.)

@JohnBollinger Where can I read up more on this? I will try using the expect script as soon as I reach home.

Expect example dealing with \033[6n: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48112002/13534458
